# Counting the Frequency of three words

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter

I have the code below to find the frequencies of two word phrases. I need to do the same for three word phrases.

However the code below does not seem to work for 3 word phrases.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

sentence = "I love TV show makes me happy, I love also comedy show makes me feel like flying"
words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
two_words = [' '.join(ws) for ws in zip(words, words[1:])]
wordscount = {w:f for w, f in Counter(two_words).most_common() if f > 1}
wordscount
{'show makes': 2, 'makes me': 2, 'I love': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.Counter` on an iterable of 3-word groupings. The latter is constructed via a generator comprehension and list slicing.

```
from collections import Counter

three_words = (words[i:i+3] for i in range(len(words)-2))
counts = Counter(map(tuple, three_words))
wordscount = {' '.join(word): freq for word, freq in counts.items() if freq > 1}

print(wordscount)

{'show makes me': 2}
```

Notice we don't use `str.join` until the very end to avoid unnecessary repeated string operations. In addition, `tuple` conversion is required for `Counter` as `dict` keys must be hashable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest factoring the functionality out to [a seperate function](https://github.com/L3viathan/toolib/blob/master/tools.py#L364):

```
def nwise(iterable, n):
    """
    Iterate over n-grams of an iterable.
    Has a bit of an overhead compared to pairwise (although only during
    initialization), so the two functions are implemented independently.
    """
    iterables = [iter(iterable) for _ in range(n)]
    for index, it in enumerate(iterables):
        for _ in range(index):
            next(it)
    yield from zip(*iterables)
```

Then you can do

```
two_words = [" ".join(bigram) for bigram in nwise(words, 2))]
```

and

```
three_words = [" ".join(trigram) for trigram in nwise(words, 3))]
```

and so on.
You can then use `collections.Counter` on top of that:

```
three_word_counts = Counter(" ".join(trigram) for trigram in nwise(words, 3))
```

Comment: This is nice. I just feel expensive `str.join` should be delayed until the final filtering on minimum count step.

Comment: @jpp I doubt that's going to be an issue, but you could also directly feed `nwise(words, 3)` into a Counter and `str.join` on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Try `zip(words, words[1:], words[2:])`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter
import re

sentence = "I love TV show makes me happy, I love also comedy show makes me feel like flying"
words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)

three_words = [' '.join(ws) for ws in zip(words, words[1:], words[2:])]
wordscount = {w:f for w, f in Counter(three_words).most_common() if f > 1}
print( wordscount )
```

**Output:**

```
{'show makes me': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = "I love TV show makes me happy, I love also comedy show makes me feel like flying"
words = sentence.split()
r = Counter([' '.join(words[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(words)-3)])

>>> r.most_common()[0] #get the most common 3-words
('show makes me', 2)
```